Why is water coming out the shower head when running the spout?
New pex plumbing and Moen fixtures and water comes out of shower head during tub fill. All new Pex with SharkBite cutoffs with these white pieces in SharkBite. Could this be the issue? Already installed new cartridge and spout but didn’t help.

Did you intend to post a photo? What are "these white pieces"?

Doubt if pex/sharkbite have much to do with it.  The fixture should have off, shower on, tub on, and maybe half and half.

I have encountered this when in areas with high water pressure.
The pressure is enough that even when the tub is filling there is sufficient resilient pressure that water can fill the riser to the shower head and come out there.
In one of my homes I installed a Shower control valve between the shower arm and the head.
